# execute a javascript function and button click event on enter keypress at the same time in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

This is my code

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnCompute" runat="server"  OnClick="btnCompute_Click" Text=""  onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"/>
```

when enter key press only the javascript function execute, I also want to execute the button click event on server side when user press enter key. How will I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute your `btnCompute_Click()` function, just add it to your `onkeypress` attribute and separate your commands with a semicolon.

```
onkeypress="btnCompute_Click(); return tabE(this,event)"
```

Comment: I already try that approach but the button click is not executing

Comment: do you have focus on the button when you are doing the keypress? You can probably tab to the button to try it out. Then press a key.